# Cannot automatically bind the navigation property 'Players' on entity type 'Data.Team' for the source entity set 'Teams'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 Code First.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Player
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Player name must be at least 2 characters length")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TeamClubId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamClubId")]
    public virtual Team Club { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TeamNationalId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamNationalId")]
    public virtual Team National { get; set; }

}

public class Team
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Team name must be at least 2 characters length")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TeamType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}


public class Tournament
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Tournament name must be at least 2 characters length")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }

}
```

In the DBContext class I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //player - national team relations
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasRequired<Team>(p => p.National)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    //player - club team relations
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasRequired<Team>(p => p.Club)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    //match - home team relations
    modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
        .HasRequired<Team>(p => p.HomeTeam)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    //match - away team relations
    modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
        .HasRequired<Team>(p => p.AwayTeam)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I get the following error when trying to connect via OData:

**Cannot automatically bind the navigation property 'Players' on entity type 'Data.Team' for the source entity set 'Teams' because there are two or more matching target entity sets. The matching entity sets are: Players, Tournaments.**

> [NotSupportedException: Cannot automatically bind the navigation
>   property 'Players' on entity type 'Data.Team' for the source entity
>   set 'Teams' because there are two or more matching target entity sets.
>   The matching entity sets are: Players, Tournaments.]
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EntitySetConfiguration.FindBinding(NavigationPropertyConfiguration
>   navigationConfiguration, Boolean autoCreate) +736
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmModelHelperMethods.AddNavigationBindings(EntitySetConfiguration
>   configuration, EdmEntitySet entitySet, EntitySetLinkBuilderAnnotation
>   linkBuilder, ODataModelBuilder builder, Dictionary`2 edmTypeMap,
>   Dictionary`2 edmEntitySetMap) +391
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmModelHelperMethods.AddEntitySets(EdmModel
>   model, ODataModelBuilder builder, EdmEntityContainer container,
>   Dictionary`2 edmTypeMap) +635
>
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmModelHelperMethods.BuildEdmModel(ODataModelBuilder
>   builder) +200
>
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
>   +664    ODataAPI.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) +221    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1
>   configurationCallback) +65
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot automatically bind the navigation
>   property 'Players' on entity type 'Data.Team' for the source entity
>   set 'Teams' because there are two or more matching target entity sets.
>   The matching entity sets are: Players, Tournaments.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +12582201
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot automatically bind the navigation
>   property 'Players' on entity type 'Data.Team' for the source entity
>   set 'Teams' because there are two or more matching target entity sets.
>   The matching entity sets are: Players, Tournaments.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12599232
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12438981

What's my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two navigation properties in Player pointing to Team, National and Club, and then you also have the property Players from Team, that is the one EF cannot resolve because it cannot guess if this collection is pointing to National or Team property so you have to help him, one way to do it is decorating the properties with InverseProperty attribute:

```
public class Team
{ 
    [InverseProperty("Club")]   
    public virtual ICollection<Player> ClubPlayers { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("National")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> NationalPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, i think you could do the same using fluent  mapping too.

Comment: Hello and thank you.
I can't have two ICollections.
A Team is either a National Team or a Club Team.
It contains a list of Players.

A player can play for two teams: Club and National.

If I'll have two ICiollection within a Team, one of them will always be empty.

Comment: You can have only one Collection if you should, just point to the correct Team property in Player. BTW i smell something in your design: if a given Team can be just of one type, Club or National, does not make sense that the Player will be member of one and only one Team? Why Player have to point to two Teams?

Comment: Hi and thanks, in the sport world, a player may belong to two teams at any time: a club team and a national team. That is reality and I'm trying to keep my model according to the reality.
What do you think?
Thanks again,
Janiv.

Comment: That is an interesting scenario, let me ask you, National Team  is kind of country's national selection? I mean, it will be the only one Team of that category?

Comment: Soccer National Team for example are teams such as: USA, Brazil, Argentina, Italy, Norway, etc.
Club Team for example are teams such as: Real Madrid, Barcelona, Manchester United, Ajax, etc.

Comment: National Team for example are teams such as: USA, Brazil, Argentina, etc.
Club Team examples: Real Madrid, Barcelona, Manchester United, etc.
A player, i.e. Messi, can play in two teams: Club and National. i.e. Messi plays for both Barcelona Club and Argentina National Team.

In my app, a player must play for at least one team (club or national), but most players will be part of both teams.

So, in my app:

A player has two Team property (Team Club; Team National).
A Team has one collection of players (ICollection<Player> Players), and can be of one or two types: Club or National.

Thanks,

Comment: I got you, i think your model express very well your problem, so the only technical implementation detail you left out was to point to the correct Team property in Player from Team. 
Another approach can be having a collection of Teams in Player,  but you will end up with a many to many relationship that does not express the fact that a Player can pertain upto two teams and no more. True that you can control this situation in your logic but the design will lose expressiveness. IMHO

Comment: I did not test it because it is not the right model for this logic and behavior (as explained above).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here, but my problem was a typing error on WebApiConfig.cs OData contiguration:

```
           builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
           builder.EntitySet<User>("Issues");
```

instead of

```
           builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
           builder.EntitySet<Issue>("Issues");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are in effect describing is a Many:Many relationship between Player and Team. Even though you want to specify a 1:2 relationship (player:team) the EntityFramework works with 1:1-0, 1:1, 1:many. 2 needs to be many to work properly with EF, you can use business logic to constrain it to just two if that is neccesary.

> Why is this an issue? EF requires that for each Navigation Property there is a single Collection Property on the Principal Entity... so that it can support the convention of automatically setting the ForeignKey property when an entity is added to the collection.

In your expected model, say you want to add a Player to the Team with the following code, how will EF know which of the team Ids to set on player record?

```
Player newPlayer = new Player();
Team team = db.Teams.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == 1); // Just illustrating that team is an existing data entity;
team.Players.Add(newPlayer);
// should this set TeamNationalId = 1
// or TeamClubId = 1
```

Just because you might not want to use the code above to add the players to a team does not mean that EF will simply ignore the convention.

What are your options:

1. Separate Team into 2 tables, NationalTeam and ClubTeam
2. Split the navigation property into two properties, NationalPlayers, ClubPlayers
3. Add an intermediary table TeamPlayer

I don't want you to consider option 1, and I don't think that you want to either, so I'll skip past that one...

Then there is another issue... you have a similar relationship with Team and Match, a Match has a HomeTeam and an AwayTeam, only in Match it probably bares more resemblance to reality that a Team has a Collection of HomeMatches and AwayMatches but it is essentially the same situation with different data types.

So of the 3 options above, here is some code for option 2: (thanks to [E-Bat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789776/1690217) for attribute notation of Inverse Properties)

```
public class Team
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Team name must be at least 2 characters length")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TeamType Type { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Club")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> ClubPlayers { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("National")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> NationalPlayers { get; set; }


    //public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("HomeTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("AwayTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }

}
```

Now if that is an issue for some of your business logic code, the following class definition might help, by adding the Players and Matches properties to Team it might simplify processing, note that you also have to initialize the collections in the constructor to avoid errors, but you would do this anyway for navigation properties to avoid issues during serialization:

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        ClubPlayers = new HashSet<Player>();
        NationalPlayers = new HashSet<Player>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Team name must be at least 2 characters length")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TeamType Type { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Club")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> ClubPlayers { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("National")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> NationalPlayers { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Player> Players
    {
        get
        {
            return ClubPlayers.Union(NationalPlayers);
        }
    }

    [InverseProperty("HomeTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("AwayTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Match> Matches
    {
        get
        {
            return HomeMatches.Union(AwayMatches);
        }
    }

}
```

Lets consider Option 3. An Intermediary table of TeamPlayers. This will allow you to add more metadata about the relationship, such as Sign/from date and end date. Maybe they are a temporary transfer or loan player?

Note that the above reasons do not really apply for option 3 in the context of the Matches relationship, a match will always have exactly 2 teams, and these teams wont change over time. Option 2 is in IMO the best one for the matches scenario.

You already have Year in the matches, which means you want to track and keep data over many seasons, there is a good probability that over the years players will change teams, your current model will not support this, for instance to run a report on the players in a grand final 5 years ago will either show too many or not enough players depending on player attrition rates... it's just a thought. Option 3 opens up some new possibilities for future functionality and reporting.